# Read from text file as a char array

Tags: matlab, file-io

I want to read from a text file and process the text (compress incrept).
I am using the `textread` function in MATLAB. My problem is that it is not reading the white spaces correctly.

Here is the code:

```
w=textread('in.txt','%c','delimiter','\n','whitespace','');

e=double(w);
[z,x]=size(e);
r=vec2mat(e,ceil(z/100));
r=uint8(r);
imwrite(r,'jocop.gif')
[t,y]=norm2lzw(uint8(e),z);
u=vec2mat(t,ceil(z/100));
imwrite(double(u),'compro.gif')
```

You will notice that I am using `'%c'` in order to get a char array  and not a cell array, but I still cannot get the whitespaces. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your `''` is not a white space - it's an empty character (there's no space between the quotes).

```
w=textread('in.txt','%c','delimiter','\n','whitespace',' ');
```

is the proper way to do it.

Comment: thank you very much, sometimes i do miss up, but still                   it is the same                                                          1INTRODUCTIOAnumberofissuesmakethedesignofthevideoserver,inavideoondemandapplication,difficult.First,

Comment: What is contained in your text file? Can you provide an example?

Comment: ya for sure the first paragraph is the original afrom the in.txt and the second one is the output in matlab:
INTRODUCTIOAnumber of issues make the design of the video server, in a
video-on-demand application, difficult. First, a video server
needs to simultaneously provide video services to multiple
clients and guarantee the quality of service for each client.

output:
1INTRODUCTIOAnumberofissuesmakethedesignofthevideoserver,inavideo-on-demandapplication,difficult.First,avideoserverneedstosimultaneouslyprovidevideoservicestomultipleclientsandguaranteethequalityofserviceforeachclient.

Comment: this is only a very small paragraph of the in.txt